# Accuracy metric of a subsection of categories in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, metrics, tensor

I've got a 3-class classification problem. Let's define them as classes 0,1 and 2. In my case, class 0 is not important - that is, whatever gets classified as class 0 is irrelevant. What's relevant, however, is accuracy, precision, recall, and error rate only for classes 1 and 2. I would like to define an accuracy metric that only looks at a subsection of the data that relates to 1 and 2 and gives me a measure of that as the model is training. I am not asking for code for accuracy or f1 or precision/recall - those I've found and can implement myself. What I'm asking is for code that can help select a subsection of the categories to perform these metrics on. 
Visually, with a confusion matrix:
Given:

```
>  0   1   2
>0 10  3   4
>1 2   5   1
>2 8   5   9
```

I would like to only perform an accuracy measure in-training for the following subset only:

```
>  1   2
>1 5   1
>2 5   9
```

Possible idea:
Concatenate a categorized, argmaxed y_pred and argmaxed y_true, drop all instances where 0 appears, re-unravel them back into a one_hot array, and do a simple binary accuracy on what remains?

Edit: 
I've tried to exclude the 0-class through this code, but it doesn't make sense. the 0-category gets effectively wrapped into the 1-category (that is, the true positives of both 0 and 1 end up being labeled as 1). Still looking for help - can anybody help out please?

```
#this solution does not work :(
def my_acc(y_true, y_pred):
#excluding the 0-category
y_true_cust = y_true[:,np.r_[1:3]]
y_pred_cust = y_pred[:,np.r_[1:3]]
#binary accuracy source code, slightly edited
y_pred_cat = Ker.round(y_pred_cust)
eql_cust = Ker.equal(y_true_cust, y_pred_cust)
return Ker.mean(eql_cust, axis = -1)
```

@ Ashwin Geet D'Sa

```
correct_guesses_3cat = 10 + 5 + 9
print(correct_guesses_3cat)
24

total_guesses_3cat = 10+3+4+2+5+1+8+5+9
print(total_guesses_3cat)
47

accuracy_3cat = 24/47
print(accuracy_3cat)
51.1 %

correct_guesses_2cat =5 + 9
print(correct_guesses_2cat)
14

total_guesses_2cat = 5+1+5+9
print(total_guesses_2cat)
20

accuracy_2cat = 14/20
print(accuracy_2cat)
70.0 %
```

Comment: Do you just want the code to select the subsection?

Comment: Yes please. If you are generous enough to mesh your code with the accuracy metric for either a binary or categorical entropy, please do so. My main problem is simply selecting the subsection - as someone new to programming, I am having a hard time figuring that out with the Keras backend (tensors are harder to work with than simple Numpy arrays), but I think many others, and myself included, would really appreciate a clear example of both selecting the subsection, and then performing an accuracy analysis on it.

Comment: Primary goal = selecting the subsection in a Keras-friendly tensory way. Secondary goal = using that subsection to perform an accuracy measurement on it (or F1, precision, recall, etc).

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa any chance you can figure this problem out?

Comment: Can you please tell us why the solution that you have posted doesn't work?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa  The 0-category gets effectively wrapped into the 1-category (that is, the true positives of both 0 and 1 end up being labeled as 1). From the example above, you would end up having the metric calculate accuracy on the (0,0) + the (1,1) true positives. It would end up with the (1,1) true positives having the value of 15.

Comment: I am a little confused. If you could post the desired input and the output, would possibly help you better.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa please see the edit to the post to see what I mean

Comment: Well, I understood your problem. Could you please share the complete piece of code (If you can), so as to know the data type, other parameters and the flow of code, so that a right solution can be tried (I cannot guarantee a solution, but it may be possible)

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa with this being the accuracy metric to be used with a one_hot_encoded y_pred and y_true, it doesn't actually matter what data types or code flow there is; as long as "categorical_accuracy" can be used, this metric should be substitutable.

Comment: Well, are you able to get the confusion matrix as a numpy matrix?

Comment: I was, but when I perform operations on it as a numpy matrix, and then try to write them with the Keras backend, I get errors. It needs to be done with Keras right off the bat (I think). What can you contribute to this problem/solution?

Comment: Now that you have put me under confusion. If you can solve this problem using Numpy way, numpy offers functions to calculate F-Score. I think, you must get the intended results that way.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa what I'm trying to change is the Keras backend metric for when it calculates Accuracy (for example) in-training. The in-training part is key. It's trivial to calculate F1 or precision in a post-training environment - I'm trying to change the Keras metric in the Keras Backend https://keras.io/metrics/